# kernel panic on /usr/bin/switch_root -d

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, kernel-panic

I use arch linux and after an update about a month ago I can't boot the system anymore.

The logs show a kernel panic caused by calling `/usr/bin/switch_root` with arg `-d`.

I've tried a live cd boot and `chroot` into the system, followed by another update, but no luck. Also tried renaming the `initramfs-fallback.img` (name probably not correct, I don't recall it perfectly) to `initramfs.img`. I read somewhere that this could be caused by the ram disk.

whatever is calling `switch_root` seems to run after arch prints out the lines

`:: Mounting '/dev/sdc4' on real root 
:: Running cleanup hook [udev]`

What do you think?

Kernel panic picture:
[image]

Comment: The release notes for util-linux show no changes to switch_root for the last two releases, and there have been no Arch patches. Paste the full journal from a failed boot.

Comment: @jasonwryan I think it's this man: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=9737a1671117e2d8ade95cd46df2c0787d9266cd

Comment: That would seem unlikely: this would be an issue affecting a lot more people. Please paste the actual journal.

Comment: @jasonwryan could you advise on pasting the journal, please? I booted to the live system, did a chroot into the old one, and read the output of `journalctl`, the last entries. It didn't look abnormal. Is that output what you want me to paste? I took a picture of the kernel panic at least.

Comment: Paste the text, not a screenshot https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Pastebin_clients

Comment: What bootloader are you using, and what is the full kernel command line it runs?

Comment: @JigglyNaga clover. `root=UUID=54a66fa3-6d48-4387-a2c0-a70989910ef1 rw add_efi_memmap initrd=/initramfs-linux.img video=1920x1080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by chrooting into the unbootable system and running pacman -Suy with /boot mounted correctly. Linux was updated and mkinitcpio was run automatically. My /boot is in another partition and the first time I did pacman -Suy, I didn't mount it.